# Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts error

Tags: unit-test, callout, failing-tests

This is my controller class.

```java
public with sharing class RSLeadReportcontroller {

    public List<RSLeadReport> ConsoleWrapperList{get;set;}
    
    public List<RSLeadReport> getperformcallout(){
    
        ConsoleWrapperList = new List<RSLeadReport>();
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setTimeout(60000);
        
        String authorization= String.valueOf([SELECT Authentication__c FROM RS_External_Endpoint__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'RS_Token' LIMIT 1].Authentication__c);   
        
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+authorization);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint('https://rsdv-dt-loc-na-api.exxonmobil.com/api/v2/search/get/leads');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        res = http.send(req);
        
        if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){
        
            ConsoleWrapperList=(List<RSLeadReport>)json.deserialize(res.getbody(),List<RSLeadReport>.class);
        
        }
            
        return consolewrapperlist;
   }
        
    public PageReference exportToExcel(){
        PageReference retURLExcel = new PageReference('/apex/WebApp_Leads_excel');
        return retURLExcel;
    } 
          
}
```

And this is my test class.

```java
@isTest
public class Test_RSLeadReportcontroller{
 
  @testSetup
  public static void setupTestData(){
    Test.startTest();
    Lead lead_Obj = new Lead(LastName = 'LastName885', FirstName = 'First641', MiddleName = 'Middl705', Company = 'Company493', Street = 'PratapNagar', City = 'Miami', State = 'Florida', PostalCode = '302022', Country = 'USA', MobilePhone = '54343-63122', Email = 'Email28@test.com', Website = 'http://test29.com', Status = 'New', Webapp_Lead_ID__c = 'Webap415', Lead_Pardot__c = false);
    Insert lead_Obj; 
    Test.stopTest();
  }
  
  public class RSCallout implements HttpCalloutMock{

            public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
                // Create a fake response
                HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
                response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                response.setBody('{"data": {"identity": {"accountGroup": {"code": "0001"},"salesforceId": "0014100001eCl2U", "tradingName": "CPAC ROOF TILE" }}}');
                response.setStatusCode(200);
                //response.setStatus('Customer Found');
                return response;
            }        
  } 

  public static testMethod void test_exportToExcel_UseCase1(){
    List<Lead> lead_Obj  =  [SELECT LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Company,Street,City,State,PostalCode,Country,MobilePhone,Email,Website,Status,Webapp_Lead_ID__c from Lead];
    System.assertEquals(true,lead_Obj.size()>0);
    RSLeadReportcontroller obj01 = new RSLeadReportcontroller();
    obj01.ConsoleWrapperList = new List<RSLeadReport>();
    obj01.exportToExcel();
  }

  public static testMethod void test_getperformcallout_UseCase1(){
    Test.startTest();
    List<Lead> lead_Obj  =  [SELECT LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Company,Street,City,State,PostalCode,Country,MobilePhone,Email,Website,Status,Webapp_Lead_ID__c from Lead];
    System.assertEquals(true,lead_Obj.size()>0);
    
    RSLeadReportcontroller obj01 = new RSLeadReportcontroller();
    obj01.ConsoleWrapperList = new List<RSLeadReport>();
    obj01.getperformcallout();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new RSCallout());
    Test.stopTest();  
  }
             
}
```

Comment: `testMethod` is deprecated, have you faced the same issue annotating the test method with `@isTest`?

Comment: @JefersonChaves Derek's answer is correct, but this is a good point. They should fix that problem.

Comment: Fair enough @sfdcfox, I also could not understand how this is supposed to work if the `Test.setMock` is called after the call to the callout method `getperformcallout`.

Comment: @JefersonChaves The only way I can think that it _might_ work is if the callout were in a future/queueable/scheduleable/batch class (with `setMock()` called after the async method is first called, but before `Test.stopTest()`). The idea being that since the async code isn't actually run until `Test.stopTest()` is executed, the mock is technically still set before the code that needs it is executed. Even if that does work, I don't think it'd be something anyone should recommend.

Comment: @DerekF: thanks a million for all the clarification, when I wrote the comments I was not seeing your answer, yet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Test.setMock()` *prior to* running the code that is trying to make the callout, not afterwords.

Calling that method is what causes Salesforce to substitute the real callout for the mock one that you're providing (when the callout is attempted).

Comment: +1 though, according to the docs, you should call Test.setMock after Test.startTest as well.